# How to refresh form values which have been prevoiusly inserted in jsf?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

> In my application, I am adding form data in database on click of submit button.But the problem is, when user refreshes the page, the data added one more time into the database and so on...
>
> What can be the solution for this, please some body give me good link/solution for this problem...
>
> Thanks a lot.

Code :

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{co.createAction()}" />

public String createAction() {
  if (login.registerUser().equals("success")) {
    return "index?faces-redirect=true";
  } else {
    return "failure";
  }
}

public String registerUser() {
  if (serv.createRegUser(reg)) {
    return "success";
  } else {
    return "failed";
  }
}

public boolean createRegUser(Registration reg) { 
  try { 
    initJpa(); 
    regJpa.create(reg); 
    return true; 
  } catch(Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    return false; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Probably something is wrong and as you observed you add data to database on refresh. For a more detailed diagnosis give us more relevant details like code etc.

Comment: Here is my code <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{co.createAction()}"/>
public String createAction(){
 if(login.registerUser().equals("success")){
return "index?faces-redirect=true";
}else{
return "failure";
}}public String registerUser(){
if(serv.createRegUser(reg)){
 return "success";
 }else{
 return "failed"; }
}
` public boolean createRegUser(Registration reg)
    {
        try
        {
            initJpa();
            regJpa.create(reg);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
  } }`

Comment: @user3231655 so even after 10 minutes have passed, it still doesn't cross you mind to edit your question and add the code there rather than making it unreadable in a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Also avoid using void methods in JSF. If you want to return back to same page use the same page viewid.
Try to put the following code:

```
public String submit() {
    // ...

    return "viewid?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

The reference is taken from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850831/how-to-avoid-re-execution-of-last-form-submit-action-when-the-page-is-refreshed).

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by several factors :

1 - Your function adding the item in the database is called each time the view is displayed.

This could be caused by a `@PostConstruct` annotation on the aforesaid method. This could also be caused by an element calling this method from the view.

2 - Your method for inserting object in database is persisting 2 objects

3 - Your form is submitted more than once

4 - You inserted a second object if the DB when you observed

Comment: Here is my code <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{co.createAction()}"/>
public String createAction(){
 if(login.registerUser().equals("success")){
return "index?faces-redirect=true";
}else{
return "failure";
}}public String registerUser(){
if(serv.createRegUser(reg)){
 return "success";
 }else{
 return "failed"; }
}
` public boolean createRegUser(Registration reg)
    {
        try
        {
            initJpa();
            regJpa.create(reg);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
  } }`