# confirm form resubmission problem in primefaces 8

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hello I have a form in my webpage. I search and data comes to my table. if I click to a row, redirect to another webpage. if I want to return back browser ask to me :

Confirm Form Resubmission

This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed.
Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
ERR_CACHE_MISS

I use primefaces 8, javascript:history.back()(for back to previous page).
If I open the developer tools(F12) problem is disappering interestingly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid re-execution of last form submit action when the page is refreshed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850831/how-to-avoid-re-execution-of-last-form-submit-action-when-the-page-is-refreshed)